# Using programming languages on top of different OSs

Tags: android, ios, linux, windows, operating-system

Could somebody help me 'to stack' my understanding on where various programming languages sit on different OSs? Starting from the bottom - the basic metal computer would understand only machine code or assembler. It means that OS, let's say Linux, is written in C and compiled to machine code, right? Or Assembler?

If you have Linux written in C, does it mean that C compiler is already there by default, and I can write any simple program in C, place it to any folder and run it from the command line? 
I see some Linux distributions like Ubuntu are coming with folders /perl and /python. I assume these are compilers or interpreters of other high level languages and come as add-on to these particular OS distributions. If I want to run Java, I would add Java JVM and so on. 
However C is by default language for Linux? Or C++ also would work out of the box?

Then, if I check Wikipedia, I see following *written in*:

- Windows: C, C++, Assembly
- OS X: C, C++, Objective C
- iOS: C, C++, Objective C, Swift
- Android: C, C++, Java

Does it mean that any "Hello World" program written in respective language for each OS would run out of the box?

Could I write hardware driver, theoretically, in Swift for iOS? Or some languages are for low level tasks and some are for end user apps?

Could I write program in C and run it on iOS and Android? Or am I restricted to Objective-C/Swift/Java?

To run any other language on top of above I would need to add respective additional software such as compiler/interpreter/VM. Correct?

Comment: No C code runs without being compiled first. Even an assembler is a simple compiler, you cannot just run text files containing assembly programs directly, either. The compiler is not built into the OS. After code has been compiled to machine code, it does not matter to the machine what language it has been originally in.

Comment: This question basically means: `How does programming languages, compilers, and operating system work?`

Comment: The CPU only processes binary instruction codes and data.  That's it.

Answer (score 1):

> If you have Linux written in C, does it mean that C compiler is already there by default

No, you would need GCC or other C compilers installed. This depends entirely on which Linux distribution you are using.

Same goes for Windows(partly written in C) and all other OSs, you can't compile C programs without having a compiler installed.

> However C is by default language for Linux? Or C++ also would work out of the box?

Linux has no default language, the kernel is written in C and assembly. The compiled binary provides an interface for applications/services to run on top. You can think of it as an abstraction for the hardware. To be more specific: the notion of default language does not exist. As long as a program compiles to a compatible binary that the OS can execute, the program will run.

> Does it mean that any "Hello World" program written in respective language for each OS would run out of the box?

(Assuming that "program written" means code)

Depends on which language you write your Hello world program in. For **compiled** language like C/C++, it is *write once compile everywhere*, which means that the code is portable but needs to be compiled to binary on the target platform in order to execute it. (This is only true if you make the code portable).

For **interpreted**(sorta*) languages such as Java, the code is first compiled to bytecode and then executed in VMs on the target platform.

Generally speaking, you need to setup a development environment for the code to compile. That means getting the SDK, compilers, and tools installed.

> Could I write hardware driver, theoretically, in Swift for iOS? Or some languages are for low level tasks and some are for end user apps?

Depends on the OS and Design. In the case of iOS and Swift, Swift interpolates with Objective C. What that means is that you can call Objective C methods from Swift. So you can write drivers in Swift.

Now, **managed** language such as C# and Java might not be suitable for writing device drivers because it lacks low level access to the hardware. In **unmanaged** language such as C, memory and BIOS are exposed to the programmer, making driver development straightforward.

> Could I write program in C and run it on iOS and Android? Or am I restricted to Objective-C/Swift/Java?

It depends on the platform and/or the Application binary interface.

In Android, you can program in C/C++ using the NDK or just use Java. In iOS, you don't have a lot of options. Swift along with Objective C/C/C++ are your only choice.(Unless you go for third party solutions such RoboVM)

> To run any other language on top of above I would need to add respective additional software such as compiler/interpreter/VM. Correct?

Correct.

*NOTE: Java itself is not interpreted. The compiled bytecode is. This is similar to C#. A real interpreted language would be something like JavaScript.

Comment: Swift is not an interpreted language by any means, and calling Java that is also a bit wrong since it's first compiled and usually JITted and not interpreted. Also, a *language* does not lack access to hardware, it is the environment that defines it. There is an operating system written in C#. I also code for iOS in C and C++, so Swift and Obj-C are definitely not the only options.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that is written in C, C++ and Assembly first becomes machine code.  ALL software that actually executes on the hardware is machine code.

Your OS is composed of the only machine code that is allowed to perform certain operations (mostly related to controlling the hardware).  This allows the OS to act as a sort of gatekeeper to the hardware.  Regular programs access the hardware by calling functions that the OS exposes.

The langauge that the OS is written in doesn't matter to programs running on that OS.  Basically, whatever tools translate your source code to machine code (compilers, assemblers, etc) care about the langauge, but after that its binary all the way down.

Comment: Unless you are writing your program in LOGO... then its turtles all the way down.  :-)